# Web Services response contains invalid "?" before and after

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ejb, websphere

I am upgrading my application infrastructure, earlier my application(written in 2006) was deployed on WAS6 now upgrading it to WAS8.5. The issue is: I have a EJB 2.1 application which is consuming SOAP web service on some other server outside my network. When i call the web service it sends correct request, i can see it on console but when i receive response it contains "?" before and after the response. due to which i got error: `00000076 SystemErr     R [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.` 
I suspect this is due to some configuration i missed while installing because response text is correct but the HTTP response wrapped around it is creating problem and adding "?".
Thanks in advance.
Below is the response i am getting:
     `?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
      <session_response 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <return_code>0</return_code>
      <token>4674cfcf-e465-4550-a2d0-7fb5a1cff69b</token>
      <userid>ABC</userid>
      <system_error_code>0</system_error_code>
      <account_locked>False</account_locked>
      <IsFirstLogon>False</IsFirstLogon>
      <RoleDescription>USER</RoleDescription>
      <LastLogonTimestamp>07/28/2014 7:54:05 AM</LastLogonTimestamp>
      </session_response>?`

Comment: you need to use UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding for your response

Comment: Since you are upgrading application server and application was running on WAS 6.1, Web service is JAX-RPC?

Comment: @Miljenko web-service is JAX-RPC. There is not much difference between jax-ws and jax-rpc on implementation front. Will it make any difference if I upgrade it to any other version of SOAP ?

Comment: @blackberry dev I don't think it matters. JAX-WS is OK because it is already shipped with WAS.

Comment: @blackberry dev It seems your SOAP response contains extra BOM character. Please take a look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM22905. I guess your best bet is to create a and register JAX-WS Message Handler that would remove these characters before passing to JAX-WS unmarshaller. Or you can open a IBM PMR.

Comment: An example for BOM removal: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html

Comment: @Miljenko thanks, but its not BOM character for sure, can you provide me any link how to make JAX-RPC into JAX-WS as I am new to web services.

Comment: @blackberry dev Here is a link on IBM site with detailed explnanation how to create JAX-WS web service: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jax/ws-jax.html. But I don't think there is a need to convert JAX-RPC service into JAX-WS because JAX-RPC should work on WAS 8.5 because JAX-RPC services should just work...

Comment: @Miljenko yes it should work fine, thanks for your help.